# What's the use of subsection directive in the assembler

Tags: assembly, directive

I did't find so much explanation about subsection directive in GNU Assembler doc, after doing some test i find after compilation there will mot have individual subsection section, if we have the section .test, than define .subsection 1, no .test.1 section in the object file, only test section int the obj, so what's the use of subsection, Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see it allows you to go back and forth between subsections with the .next and .previous instructions. In most cases, if you just write your code in assembly, you probably won't need them. That's probably a lot more useful to compilers, making it easier to deal with some situations where you do not yet have all the data at hand.